# Getting differing theoretical and simulated values of V{thevenin's} on LTSPICE

Tags: ltspice, thevenin

[image: Circuit Diagram]

I got this question to find the thevenin's voltage across the load resistor RL when R = 5 ohm. I made the schematic circuit in LTSPICE and performed a DC op simulation on the circuit and got the value of 3.3871 at v0. Now when I did the same analysis theoretically I am getting the same value as V(n003) i.e. 10.1613, my reasoning being that since we open-circuit the load there won't be any current flowing through the current dependent voltage source thus the voltage being 10.1613, but I'm not sure if that is right.

Did I do something wrong with the simulation or with my theoretical calculation? I have tried solving this theoretically multiple times to get the same answer but I don't understand why would LTS show anything different. Some Guidance would be much appreciated.

[image: Schematic Diagram of the circuit in LTSPICE]

Comment: Flip V3 around. That's your problem. Current pointing away from the (+) terminal of a voltage supply is negative-valued since it is providing power and not dissipating power. If you doubt me on this, test it. Set up a voltage supply and one resistor as its load. Check what LTspice provides as the voltage source's current value.

Comment: The Thevenin voltage is when the output is unloaded hence, it's not called the Thevenin voltage when RL is connected.

Comment: @periblepsis I did flip V3 around, I'm getting a value of 16V on v0, again which I think isn't correct. Open circuited the load as Andy suggested, I still get the same voltage.

Comment: @GroundBreaking-Tap I've not analyzed the circuit. I was only pointing out how to interpret current direction with respect to its sign when using a voltage source. It was wired wrong given how you used H1. Did you test and verify my statement using the simple circuit I suggested?

Comment: @GroundBreaking-Tap I just [did the simulation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kc8Ma.png) and, without RL included, I get a Thevenin voltage of about 16.9355. From solving the equations I get 16.9354838709677 (more digits.) So, I have to say that I'm having no problems. Neither with my way of computing results from theory or from using the LTspice simulator. They both agree with each other.

Comment: @GroundBreaking-Tap Sounds like you need to show your hand calculations...

Comment: @periblepsis Here is what I did [Solution](https://i.imgur.com/6iUoDxV.jpg). Just saw that the I through v0 is negative so the voltage would be negative as well. This does match with the answer I got. I did get 16.3 as well when I flipped v3 around, but wouldn't that go against with what the question asked in the first place?